# Not able to read data from the input file

Tags: python, numpy, file-handling

I am trying to read the following input file, Here is the pastebin link of my code and input file [click here](http://pastebin.com/pzWM1siQ):

```
 1       42.5340919495   4.22926330566
 2       41.3636322021   2.87980079651
 3       38.7423553467   3.40052604675
 4       36.631401062    2.33657073975
 5       35.0620422363   3.57421207428
```

This is how I am generating the input file:

```
with open('position/output.dat','a') as output:

    for i in range(0, len(position_mean)):

        output.write('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(i+1, position_mean[i] , position_std[i]) + "\n" )

output.close()
```

This is how I am reading the input file:

```
with open("position/output.dat", 'r') as f:
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    for line in f:
        if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'):
            continue
        row = line.split("\t")
        x.append(float(row[0]))
        y.append(float(row[1]))
        z.append(float(row[2]))

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
z = np.asarray(z)
```

but when I print x, y, z, no output is being shown. What could be the possible error here?

Comment: Pease show the actual indentation!

Comment: With correct indentation, this *does* print output for `x`, `y` and `z` (after adding in the appropriate print statements and changing `line.split("\t")` to `line.split()`). I'm voting to close this as a problem that cannot be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation looks like it might be causing the issue.

```
with open("stack_test.txt", 'r') as f:
    x = []
    y = []
    z = []
    for line in f:
       if not line.strip() or line.startswith('@') or line.startswith('#'):
          continue
       row = line.split("\t")
       x.append(float(row[0]))
       y.append(float(row[1]))
       z.append(float(row[2]))

    x = np.asarray(x)
    y = np.asarray(y)
    z = np.asarray(z)
```

Comment: I'm 83% sure that this is the code OP is actually running and the indentation issues in his code are just a formatting error in his post.

Comment: @Tagc Sorry, my internet was down. Couldn't reply. You were 83% right but it was a post formatting issue.